# Setting provisioned concurrency for lambda conditionally using serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

The lambda function is created using serverless(2.22) and is deployed using codebuild (standard5.0). I want to conditionally set the provisioned concurrency only for UAT and Prod env and not for dev and test env.

These are the things I tried:

*serverless.yml:*

```yaml
    ...
    alarms:
      - functionErrors
    Conditions:
      isProdOrUAT: {"Fn::Or": [{"${opt:stage}": "prod"}, {"${opt:stage}": "uat"}]} 
functions:
  TestApi:
    handler: test.api.StreamLambdaHandler::handleRequest
    description: Lambda function for the Test API
    timeout: 20
    custom: !If [isProdOrUAT, "${file(./provisionedconcurrency.yml)}", !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
```

*provisionedconcurrency.yml*

```
provisionedConcurrency: "${ssm:/${opt:stage}/TestsServiceProvisionedConcurrency}"
```

In this case what happens is, it imports the file successfully, build also passes. But there is no provisioned concurrency attached in the lambda configuration for UAT and Prod.

*serverless.yml*

```yaml
 ...
    alarms:
      - functionErrors
    Conditions:
      isProdOrUAT: {"Fn::Or": [{"${opt:stage}": "prod"}, {"${opt:stage}": "uat"}]} 
functions:
  TestApi:
    handler: test.api.StreamLambdaHandler::handleRequest
    description: Lambda function for the Test API
    timeout: 20
    provisionedConcurrency: !If [isProdOrUAT, "${ssm:/${opt:stage}/TestsServiceProvisionedConcurrency}", !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
```

In this case getting the following error

```
Error --------------------------------------------------
  Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: [/Resources/TestApiProvConcLambdaAlias/Type/ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig/ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

Checked the `serverless-state.json`, found this to be there.

```json
    "Name": "provisioned",
      "ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig": {
        "ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions": null
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sls added support for stripping null properties about a year ago so now it's pretty strait-forward:

```
custom:
  stages:
    dev:
    # no need to set value for provisionedConcurrency
    uat:
      provisionedConcurrency: 5
    prod:
      provisionedConcurrency: 5

functions:    
    TestApi:
        handler: test.api.StreamLambdaHandler::handleRequest
        description: Lambda function for the Test API
        timeout: 20
        provisionedConcurrency: ${self:custom.stages.${self:provider.stage}.provisionedConcurrency, null}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to keep it simple, without additional yml configs and complicated if-statement and take benefit of [Conditional variable](https://forum.serverless.com/t/conditional-serverless-yml-based-on-stage/1763/2):

```yaml
custom:
    provisionedConcurrency:
        prod: 5
        uat: 5
        default: 0
        
functions:    
    TestApi:
        handler: test.api.StreamLambdaHandler::handleRequest
        description: Lambda function for the Test API
        timeout: 20
        provisionedConcurrency: ${self:custom.provisionedConcurrency.${self:provider.stage}, self:custom.provisionedConcurrency.default}
```

Comment: upvote but: serverless 2.x does not like a provisionedConcurrency of 0 and will issue both a configuration warning and a deprecation warning:
- `Serverless: Configuration warning:
Serverless:   at 'functions.testapi.provisionedConcurrency': should be >= 1`

- `Serverless: Deprecation warning: Starting with next major, Serverless will throw on configuration errors by default. Adapt to this behavior now by adding "configValidationMode: error" to service configuration
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#CONFIG_VALIDATION_MODE_DEFAULT`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. Nowadays you can do this (YAML example)

```
Parameters:
 ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions:
    Description: The amount of provisioned concurrency to allocate for the function, use 0 to ignore setting
    Type: Number
    MinValue: 0
    MaxValue: 10
    Default: 0

Conditions:
  UseProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: !Not [!Equals [!Ref ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions, 0]]


Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
          ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig: !If
           - UseProvisionedConcurrentExecutions
           - ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: !Ref ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions
           - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'here
```

Comment: I wish there was some explanation to what is going on here. It looks like some of the code is pasted in the wrong place by accident.

Comment: You are right, something happened during pasting. I fixed the example snippet.